# How to use unique_ptr with std::copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I googled and found nothing. I guess I just don't know how to type the right question.

Okay, my simple MemoryBlock class has two member data, `int size` and `int* data`. So to build a copy constructor, I use std::copy to do the memory copy. Now I would like to try the C++ smart pointer to replace the raw pointer. Say using the `unique_ptr<int> data`. What is the equivalence of the following code? Because now, `rhs.data + size` won't work.

```
std::copy(rhs.data, rhs.data + size, data);
```

Comment: `std::copy(rhs.data.get(), rhs.data.get() + size, data.get());`

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Wouldn't `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` be better?

Comment: To clarify campster's comment, `std::unique_ptr<int>` owning a pointer allocated with `new[]` would be bad, because `std::unique_ptr<int>::~unique_ptr` would then have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am just trying to play around with some c++ basics and trying to figure out what these new c++ features mean to building a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you have to allocate the array for the created object and then you can copy values to it. For example

```
MemoryBlock( const MemoryBlock &m ) : size( m.size ), data( new int[m.size] )
{
    std::copy(m.data.get(), m.data.get() + m.size, data.get());
}
```

Take into account that the member data `data` must be declared like

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;
```

If you want to add the move constructor to the class you can define it the following way

```
MemoryBlock( MemoryBlock &&m ) : size( 0 ), data( nullptr )
{
    std::swap( m.size, size );
    std::swap( m.data, data );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`std::unique_ptr<>::get()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get), that returns a pointer to the managed object or `nullptr` if no object is owned.

I.e.:

```
std::copy(rhs.data.get(), rhs.data.get() + size, data.get());
```

As also commented by NathanOliver, another option is to replace raw memory pointer owned by `unique_ptr` with [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) altogether.